# Position: absolute overlapping with wide viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a slightly rotated div creating an asymetrical graphic on my start page. I use `overflow: hidden` to hide the overlap from that div. Everything uses absolute positioning to get the elements exactly where I want them and vw and vh to make it responsive. It looks great while the aspect ratio is "normal" but when the window approaches a 2 or 3:1 aspect ratio (like an ultrawide monitor) everything overlaps. Narrow aspect ratio is not a problem since I have it switch to mobile view before it becomes a problem.

I considered using `overflow: auto` so it wouldn't be forced to fit in the viewport but then it's possible to see the edges of the rotated div.

Is there a solution to this or is this perhaps bad practice and should be done differently?

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#body {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: red; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}


.shape {
 position: absolute;
 right: -10%;
 top: -50%;
 height: 200%;
 width: 45%;
 transform: rotate(350deg);
 background: white;
}

#welcome {
 position: absolute;
 color: black;
 z-index: 999;
 margin-left: 65vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

#welcome h1 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 7vw;
}

#welcome p {
 font-size: 4vw;
 margin-top: 0;
}

#startbtn {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 3vw;
 padding: 4vh 5.5vw 4vh 5.5vw;
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 margin-left: 65vw;
 margin-top: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
 <div class="shape"></div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="welcome" autofocus>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>More Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="button" id="startbtn" onclick="getstarted()" value="Get Started">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Did you know you can create js/css/html embeds directly in Stack Overflow? I'll do this one for you.

Comment: Recommend you post some screenshots of the issue - because I can't see it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that.

Here is a screenshot of the problem. When I set the resolution to, for example, 3800x1000, this happens. I understand why this happens but I'm wondering if there is something I can do to prevent this from happening if someone is using an ultrawide monitor or wants to resize the window that way, for some reason.

Comment: https://imgur.com/VsiulrD

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Putting the shape into the same container (I used the first wrapper) as your content should fix the problem. Why is this: Because the white shape should be in relation to your content. Also I did put the button in the same container.

And you dont need background-sizes for your body as it is just plain red.

I might have messed up your original dimensions, but this should do the trick.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(350deg);
  background: white;
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 65vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

#welcome h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 7vw;
}

#welcome p {
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#startbtn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 4vh 5.5vw 4vh 5.5vw;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 65vw;
  margin-top: 70vh;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(350deg);
  background: white;
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-left: 65vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

#welcome h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 7vw;
}

#welcome p {
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#startbtn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 4vh 5.5vw 4vh 5.5vw;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 65vw;
  margin-top: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div id="welcome" autofocus>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>More Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="startbtn" onclick="getstarted()" value="Get Started">
</div>
```